# python server and java client(another PC) Error

Tags: java, python, server, client

I made server using python on laptop. And I made client using Java on samelaptop. They were connected, and They were communicated.
But when I made client using Java on another laptop, client didn't find server 
What is wrong?? and What could I do??

Comment: Are your laptops connected to the same network?

Comment: yes ... same wifi

Answer (score 0):

On the laptop running the server:
The client can access using `localhost:<port>` or `0.0.0.0:<port>`

Connecting from another laptop (same network):
You have to connect to: `<pc-server-local-ip>:<port>`

To get `<pc-server-local-ip`, using the laptop running your server:
- Windows : type `ipconfig` in console, value next to `IPV4`
- Linux / Mac : type `ifconfig` in console, value next to `inet`